# Storing image in local drive and saving path in db

Tags: laravel

I would like to save an image in my local drive, and insert its path to a DB, and then preview the image through the website. I have no idea how to do it and also I have not found anything similar anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$filename = time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();
$destination_path = public_path('/image/');
$image->save($destination_path . $filename);
$image->image_path= $destination_path;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can **try** to do this:

```
// To save image on local drive and insert path to db.
if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
    $path = $request->image->store('public/images');
    $path = basename($path);

    $image = new Images();
    $image->photo = $path;
    $image->save();
}
```

I hope it would be helpful.